# Can I cast parseBitcodeFile return value to a Module*?

Tags: llvm

Its return type is a `ErrorOr<Module*>`. I was looking at some old code and they directly assign its return value to a `Module*` but my compiler complains that no conversion exists from `ErrorOr<Module*>` to `Module*`

Answer (score 2):

Simply invoke the `get` method of `ErrorOr`:

```
ErrorOr<Module *> ModuleOrErr = parseBitcodeFile(Buffer, Context);
std::unique_ptr<Module> M(ModuleOrErr.get());
```

Note that since `parseBitcodeFile` gives you a new `Module`, it's important to assume ownership of it using `std::unique_ptr`.

For an example of how this is done in "real life", see the `llvm::parseIR` function (in `lib/IRReader/IRReader.cpp`):

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> llvm::parseIR(MemoryBufferRef Buffer, SMDiagnostic &Err,
                                      LLVMContext &Context) {
  NamedRegionTimer T(TimeIRParsingName, TimeIRParsingGroupName,
                     TimePassesIsEnabled);
  if (isBitcode((const unsigned char *)Buffer.getBufferStart(),
                (const unsigned char *)Buffer.getBufferEnd())) {
    ErrorOr<Module *> ModuleOrErr = parseBitcodeFile(Buffer, Context);
    if (std::error_code EC = ModuleOrErr.getError()) {
      Err = SMDiagnostic(Buffer.getBufferIdentifier(), SourceMgr::DK_Error,
                         EC.message());
      return nullptr;
    }
    return std::unique_ptr<Module>(ModuleOrErr.get());
  }

  return parseAssembly(Buffer, Err, Context);
}
```